# Get information about devices in LAN network in iOS

Tags: ios, sockets

I need to get list of devices(printers, laptops, ...) and information(ip, MAC, name) for each device at iPhone. I have no idea how. Could anybody help me.

Comment: do you promise you won't misuse it?

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke yes i promise.

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke tell me the solution?

Comment: My question was rhetorical. If getting the ip and Mac address of 'EVERY' device on any connected network was this easy no one would ever connect their device to that network. You need to explain what you are trying to achieve in much more detail to get any help.

Comment: Accessing printers on the network from an iOS device is possible and a simple google or stack overflow search will give you a lot of help regarding printing.

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke My iphone is connected to a wifi network and like this there are other devices that are connected to same network like my Mac,printer, laptop etc now i want in my app to get ip address, mac address and vendor name of all the devices that are connected to same network with which my iPhone is connected. I am able to find out all the ip address on which these devices are connected but not there mac address and vendor name. I hope now every thing is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the IP-addresses you can query the ARP-table like this

```
    #include <sys/param.h>
    #include <sys/file.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <sys/sysctl.h>

    #include <net/if.h>
    #include <net/if_dl.h>
    #include "if_types.h"
    #include "route.h"
    #include "if_ether.h"
    #include <netinet/in.h>


    #include <arpa/inet.h>

    #include <err.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <netdb.h>

    #include <paths.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

        -(NSString*) ip2mac: (char*) ip
        {

            static int nflag;

            int flags, found_entry;



            NSString *mAddr = nil;
            u_long addr = inet_addr(ip);
            int mib[6];
            size_t needed;
            char *host, *lim, *buf, *next;
            struct rt_msghdr *rtm;
            struct sockaddr_inarp *sin;
            struct sockaddr_dl *sdl;
            extern int h_errno;
            struct hostent *hp;

            mib[0] = CTL_NET;
            mib[1] = PF_ROUTE;
            mib[2] = 0;
            mib[3] = AF_INET;
            mib[4] = NET_RT_FLAGS;
            mib[5] = RTF_LLINFO;
            if (sysctl(mib, 6, NULL, &needed, NULL, 0) < 0)
                err(1, "route-sysctl-estimate");
            if ((buf = malloc(needed)) == NULL)
                err(1, "malloc");
            if (sysctl(mib, 6, buf, &needed, NULL, 0) < 0)
                err(1, "actual retrieval of routing table");


            lim = buf + needed;
            for (next = buf; next < lim; next += rtm->rtm_msglen) {
                rtm = (struct rt_msghdr *)next;
                sin = (struct sockaddr_inarp *)(rtm + 1);
                sdl = (struct sockaddr_dl *)(sin + 1);
                if (addr) {
                    if (addr != sin->sin_addr.s_addr)
                        continue;
                    found_entry = 1;
                }
                if (nflag == 0)
                    hp = gethostbyaddr((caddr_t)&(sin->sin_addr),
                                       sizeof sin->sin_addr, AF_INET);
                else
                    hp = 0;
                if (hp)
                    host = hp->h_name;
                else {
                    host = "?";
                    if (h_errno == TRY_AGAIN)
                        nflag = 1;
                }



                if (sdl->sdl_alen) {

                    u_char *cp = LLADDR(sdl);

                    mAddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", cp[0], cp[1], cp[2], cp[3], cp[4], cp[5]];


                //  ether_print((u_char *)LLADDR(sdl));
                }
                else

                    mAddr = nil;



            }


            if (found_entry == 0) {
                return nil;
            } else {
                return mAddr;
            }




        }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *s = @"0.0.0.0";
    const char *c = [s UTF8String];

    NSLog(@"MAC IS %@", [self ip2mac:c]);
}
```

And you need to add these classes to your project classes

- "if_types.h"
- "route.h"
- "if_ether.h"

This function takes an IP-address string (x.x.x.x) as arg and returns the mac address as a string.